# Obtaining a given item in a Doctrine ArrayCollection

Tags: php, doctrine

Developing an API where at the start of every request, the provided API key is used to obtain the Account object which is associated with the request.

```
$account = $em->getRepository(Entity\Account\Account::class)
              ->findOneBy(['mainKey'=>$request->getHeaderLine('X-API-Key')]);
```

This Account entity contains a User's `ArrayCollection` where each of the User entities contains an `username` property which is unique for a given Account.

Given the username, how can I obtain the User entity?  I can do something like the following, however, feel I should be doing differently.

```
$user = $em->getRepository(Entity\Account\User::class)
           ->findOneBy(['accountId'=>$account->getId(), 'username'=>'John.Doe']);
```

Thanks,

PS.  I assume that `findOneBy()` is using a prepared statement behind the scenes and isn't subject to SQL injection, right?

PSS.  I just assumed that an ArrayCollection holds a group of objects, but looking at some of the docs, am now not certain.

Answer (score 0):

If `Account` is related to `User` (I suppose it is one-to-one), then `Account` should have `$user` property defined. And you can access it kinda:

```
$user = $account->getUser();
```

Where `getUser` is:

```
public function getUser()
{
    return $this->user;
}
```

Comment: An account can have many users (one-to-many) so I will need to get the one in the collection with the given username.

Answer (score 0):

Both of these approaches seem to work:

```
$criteria = \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Criteria::create()
->where(\Doctrine\Common\Collections\Criteria::expr()->eq("username", $username));
$user = $users->matching($criteria)->current();

$expr = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Expr\Comparison('username', '=', $username);
$criteria = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Criteria();
$criteria->where($expr);
$user = $users->matching($criteria)->current();
```